# Prevent Doctrine from removing a foreign key constraint

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, database-schema

I manually added a foreign key to a table.  How can I prevent SchemaTool from removing it and ideally not even reporting that it exists?  I hoped that I could use a listener to prevent it, but there doesn't appear to be a `SchemaForeignKeyDefinitionEventArgs` event.  How can this be accomplished?

```php
class DoctrineSchemaListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function onSchemaAlterTable(SchemaAlterTableEventArgs $args)
    {
        if($this->checkIfThisIsRemovingTheFk()) {
            $args->preventDefault();
        }
    }
    public function onSchemaAlterTableChangeColumn(SchemaAlterTableChangeColumnEventArgs $args)
    {
        if($this->checkIfThisIsRemovingTheFk()) {
            $args->preventDefault();
        }
    }    
    public function onSchemaColumnDefinition(SchemaColumnDefinitionEventArgs $args)
    {
        if($this->checkIfThisIsRemovingTheFk()) {
            $args->preventDefault();
        }
    }
    public function onSchemaIndexDefinition(SchemaIndexDefinitionEventArgs $args)
    {
        if($this->checkIfThisIsRemovingTheFk()) {
            $args->preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```